# Confusion about the vendor folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Firstly, I have the following sprocket directories set up:

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

However, a simple test file in vendor,

```
console.log('I\'ve been loaded,baby!');
```

is not loaded by sprockets? If I move it into app/assets/js is works then, but not in vendor. What directives do I need to set up in order for this to work? Do they have to be required individually?

Do I need to precompile even in development?

Also, there is no `images` directory in `vendor`. Many third party scripts have demo images with them. I would actually prefer to them in `vendor/images` rather than `app/assets/images`. Can this be setup?

Comment: If you are upgrading from Rails 3, please take into account that assets under lib/assets or vendor/assets are available for inclusion via the application manifests but no longer part of the precompile array. See Precompiling Assets for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Rails Guides

> Pipeline assets can be placed inside an application in one of three
>   locations: app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets

Make sure that you are placing the assets in one of the locations mentioned above.

To answer your queries:

> *If I move it into app/assets/js is works then, but not in vendor.*

It works there because of the `require_tree` directive specified in `application.js` which loads all the javascript files present in current directory (of `application.js`) i.e., `app/assets/javascripts`

```
//= require_tree .
```

The above directive doesn't load the javascript files from `vendor/assets/javascripts` which is why it doesn't work in `vendor`.

> *What directives do I need to set up in order for this to work? Do they have to be required individually?*

Yes, you would have to require them in `application.js` explicitly.

Suppose, you have `vendor/javascripts/abc_vendor.js` and  `vendor/stylesheets/abc_vendor.css`

then in `application.js` you will have to add

```
//= require abc_vendor
```

and in `application.css`

```
*= require abc_vendor
```

> *Many third party scripts have demo images with them. I would actually prefer to them in vendor/images rather than app/assets/images. Can
>   this be setup?*

Yes. It can be setup. Just create the folder `images` in `vendor/assets` directory. Add the vendor images in that folder. Suppose you added `abc_logo.jpg` in `vendor/assets/images` directory. Restart the server. And access the image as:

```
<%= image_tag "abc_logo.jpg" %>
```