# How do I tell rails not to precompile/cache a .js.erb file in my app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, actioncable, precompile

I have a messages.js.erb file in my app/assets/javascripts/channels folder that should generate code to take each chatroom from the database and create channel subscriptions for that chatroom.

**Here is my messages.js.erb file**

```
//**app/assets/javascripts/channels/messages.js.erb**

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  submitNewMessage();
});

<% Chatroom.all.each do |chatroom| %>
  App['room' + <%=chatroom.id%>] = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: 'MessagesChannel', room: <%=chatroom.id%>}, {
  received: function(data) {
   $("[data-chatroom='" + this.chatroomId + "']").removeClass('hidden');
    return $("[data-chatroom='" + this.chatroomId + "']").append(data.message);
  },

  setChatroomId: function(chatroomId) {
    this.chatroomId = chatroomId;
  }
});

<% end %>

function submitNewMessage(){
  //console.log(uid);
  $('textarea#message_content').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var msg = event.target.value;
        var chatroomId = $("[data-chatroom]").data().chatroom;
        var uid = $('#uid').val();
        //console.log(uid);
        App['room' + chatroomId].setChatroomId(chatroomId);
        App['room' + chatroomId].send({message: msg, chatroom_id: chatroomId, user_id: uid});
        $('[data-textarea="message"]').val(" ");
        return false;
     }
  });
}
```

Preferably, this file should reload every time a new chatroom is created, but rails is caching(`precompiling?`) the file(`asset?`) after first load and serving it at every request.

So, the problem is: Every time a new chatroom is created, if I want it to stream (i.e., be able to post messages to be streamed instantly to every participant of that chatroom), I need to change the file manually (by adding whitespace, or adding comments or logging to console, `something`) and save it so that rails thinks that the file has changed and reloads it, thereby iterating over all the `Chatroom`s again which contains the newly created chatroom too.

Otherwise, when I post(hit enter) on a message in a chatroom that is not streaming yet (because the cached version can't see it) I get a

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setChatroomId' of undefined
>       at HTMLTextAreaElement. (messages.self-cbf13df66ead12b7956faa24e880ce07c0289634216a096fafd4ac1c6d262f43.js?body=1:436)
>       at HTMLTextAreaElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.3.min.self-ad66c584c2469d2bb527ba7aef5893549f1554ccc8ab3ccb43bd09ce8c3bf7a1.js?body=1:5)
>       at HTMLTextAreaElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.3.min.self-ad66c584c2469d2bb527ba7aef5893549f1554ccc8ab3ccb43bd09ce8c3bf7a1.js?body=1:5)

in my browser console (developer tools). The source of the error is:

**Here is the generated messages.js code** (repeat lines trimmed for brevity)

```
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
      submitNewMessage();
    });



   App['room' + 1] = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: 'MessagesChannel', room: 1}, {
  received: function(data) {
   $("[data-chatroom='" + this.chatroomId + "']").removeClass('hidden');
    return $("[data-chatroom='" + this.chatroomId + "']").append(data.message);
  },

  setChatroomId: function(chatroomId) {
    this.chatroomId = chatroomId;
  }
});
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  App['room' + 37] = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel: 'MessagesChannel', room: 37}, {
  received: function(data) {
   $("[data-chatroom='" + this.chatroomId + "']").removeClass('hidden');
    return $("[data-chatroom='" + this.chatroomId + "']").append(data.message);
  },

  setChatroomId: function(chatroomId) {
    this.chatroomId = chatroomId;
  }
});


function submitNewMessage(){
  //console.log(uid);
  $('textarea#message_content').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var msg = event.target.value;
        var chatroomId = $("[data-chatroom]").data().chatroom;
        var uid = $('#uid').val();
        App['room' + chatroomId].setChatroomId(chatroomId); // <-- line 436
        App['room' + chatroomId].send({message: msg, chatroom_id: chatroomId, user_id: uid});
        $('[data-textarea="message"]').val(" ");
        return false;
     }
  });
}
```

I understand that this error is obvious, since `App['room' + 38]` hasn't been defined yet for the new chatroom with id 38 in which we are trying to post the message (here, all chatrooms with id's > 37)

But how do I make rails understand that this file needs to be reloaded every time a new chatroom is created. If not every time, then on every request? Basically, tell rails not to precompile/cache it so I can create chatrooms and stream from them on the go?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you used the tutorial from https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/rails-5-action-cable-with-multiple-chatroom-subscriptions/ which is a good one.
You should solve this issue not with changing the precompile. Instead supscripe to the channels more efficiently.

For example execute the method from the outside. Use a helper method to get only the needed rooms.

```
subscripeToChannels(<%= raw chatrooms_for_client %>)
```

In the subscription method check if you do not subscribed already.

```
for (var i = 0; i < App.cable.subscriptions.subscriptions.length; i++) {
    var s = App.cable.subscriptions.subscriptions[i]
    var JSONObject = JSON.parse(s.identifier);
    var room = JSONObject["room"];
    if (room == chatroomId)
    {
      preventMultipleSubscripe = true;
    }
  }
```

In case a new room got created you can execute the subscripeToChannels again in your create.js.erb file.

```
subscripeToChannels(<%= raw chatrooms_for_client %>)
```

For me, this solved it in a cleaner way

Answer (score 1):

Move your `messages.js.erb` file to the `lib/assets` or `vendor/assets` directory.

From the [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets):

> ...assets under lib/assets or vendor/assets are available for
>   inclusion via the application manifests but no longer part of the
>   precompile array.

Make sure it's not listed in your `application.js` and you should be good to go.

Comment: If I move the file to lib/assets or vendor/assets, rails does not load it at all.
All chatrooms stop streaming

Comment: This [question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168916/confusion-about-the-vendor-folder) answer says that I need to require the file in lib(or vendor) assets explicitly if I want rails to load it.
I did that, but then I ran into the same problem again

Comment: @Rahul Hmm... as I understand it, Sprockets will load assets from three locations: app/assests, lib/assets and vendor/assets as needed. Precompiling only happens for app/assets as of Rails > 3.2.6. I'll look into this some more when I have time later in the day and hopefully set up a working demo. The doc I cited certainly seems to support this interpretation.